# Colorbox - how to set data property to use POST instead of GET

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, colorbox

I'm using the colorbox plugin and according to the docs, the `data` property allows submitting GET or POST values through an ajax request. I can submit my data via GET no problem, but can't figure out how to switch to POST. I'm using serialize to set the form data in name/value pairs. I have the code below:

Is there a way to set this to POST?

```
var data = $('form').serialize();

            console.log(data);

            // Preview newsletter - bind colorbox to event
            $('a#preview').colorbox({
                width: '670px',
                href: $(this).attr('href'),
                data: data
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Comment: @Vivek Goel - ah I see, ok I'm currently passing the data as key/value pairs, like intro=&proj=7, how does this translate into an object?

Comment: from.serialize gives you string. either convert it to object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 $('form').serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

The data property will act exactly like jQuery's .load() data argument, as ColorBox uses .load() for ajax handling.

Comment: Can you provide an example?